# Linear Algebra: Find a matrix A such that T(x) is Ax for each x

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having difficulty solve this problem in my homework:

(In my notation, $[x;y]$ represents a matrix of 2 rows, 1 column)

> Let $\mathbf{x}=[x_1;x_2]$, $v_1$=[−3;5] and $v_2=[7;−2]$ and let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$  be a linear transformation that maps $\mathbf{x}$ into $x_1v_1+x_2v_2$. Find a matrix $A$ such that $T(\mathbf{x})$ is $A\mathbf{x}$ for each $\mathbf{x}$.

I am pretty clueless. So I assume that I start off with the following:

$x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 = x_1[−3;5] + x_2[7;−2]$

But I do not know what to do from here, or if this is even the correct start!

Comment: PS - Sorry, I don't know how to make the formulas look prettier.

Answer (score 5):

First: matrices with "two rows, one column" are called *vectors* (or *column vectors*).

Second: What does your function $T$ do to $\mathbf{x}=[1;0]$? What does it do to $\mathbf{x}=[0;1]$?

Or if you prefer:

Third: $A$ will be a $2\times 2$ matrix; write
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right).$$
When you multiply $A$ by $\mathbf{x}$, you get
$$A\mathbf{x} = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&d\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
ax_1 + bx_2\\
cx_1 + dx_2
\end{array}\right).$$
In order for this to be the same as
$$T(\mathbf{x}) = 
x_1\left(\begin{array}{r}-3\\5\end{array}\right) + x_2\left(\begin{array}{rr}7\\-2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}-3x_1 + 7x_2\\
5x_1 -2x_2
\end{array}\right),$$
what are the values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$?

Comment: In the step "When you multiply A by x, you get..", shouldn't there be a multiply sign after the matrix A instead of the '=' sign?

Comment: @Nunoxic: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Arturo, thank you. Is the "in order for this to be the same as" step, is that based upon the transformation rule that T(x+y) = T(x) + T(y)?

Comment: It is based on basic properties of vectors (Scalar multiplication and addition)

Comment: I apologize but I do not understand how to continue after the last step. Am I looking for values for x1 and x2 that will set x1[-3;5]+x2[7;-2]=[-3x1+7x2; 5x1-2x2] equal to each other?

Comment: For example: using the zero vector [0;0]:
0[-3;5] + 0[7;-2] = [-3(0)+7(0); 5(0)-2(0)] ... 
[0;0] + [0;0] = [0; 0] ... 
[0;0] = [0;0]?

Comment: @Derek : You're looking for the values of $a$,$b$,$c$ and $d$ that will set $\begin{pmatrix} ax_1 + bx_2 \\ cx_1 + dy_2 \end{pmatrix}$ equal to $\begin{pmatrix} -3x_1 + 7x_2 \\ 5x_1 - 2x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ for every vector $[x_1;x_2]$. The obvious choice is in front of you.

Comment: @Derek: Your choices are about $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ (which are the numbers you are *looking for*. There is one obvious choice; if this is not completely clear, consider what happens when $\mathbf{x}=[1;0]$ (i.e., when $x_1=1$ and $x_2=0$); what does that tell you about $a$ and $c$? What happens when $\mathbf{x}=[0;1]$ (i.e., when $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$)? What does that tell you about $b$ and $d$? Your final answer needs to be the values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$; that is: the matrix $A$, because the question is about finding a matrix $A$, **not** about finding a vector $\mathbf{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, I would say that

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{rr}-3&7\\5&-2\end{array}\right) \ \textrm{and} \ x'=Ax.$$
You can see this if you use 
$$x' = \left(\begin{array}{cc}x_1\\x_2\end{array}\right).$$
Then $$x_1'= -3\cdot x_1 + 7\cdot x_2 = x_1 \cdot v_{11} + x_2\cdot v_{21}$$ and $$x_2'= 5\cdot x_1-2\cdot x_2 = x_1\cdot v_{12} + x_2\cdot v_{22}$$ (here $v_{12}$ is the second element of the first $v_1$).

Comment: Also good answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I am happy that my answer was also of help.